# Как в строку записать переменную MatLab

Tags: matlab

Есть строка, в неё мне нужно внести значение переменной a1 a2 и a3

```
 str = '<html><head></head><body><tr><td>Переменная а1</td><td>a1</td></tr><tr><td>Переменная а2</td><td>а2</td></tr><tr><td>Переменная а3</td><td>а1</td></tr></body><table>'
```

Так не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию [sprintf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html).

```
src = '<html><head></head><body><tr><td>Переменная а1</td><td>%g</td></tr><tr><td>Переменная а2</td><td>%g</td></tr><tr><td>Переменная а3</td><td>%g</td></tr></body><table>'
str = sprintf(src, a1, a2, a3)
```